# Wrong body, light-years from home

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a second-hand book I read as a paperback somewhen in approx. 1978/9. It was well-dogged and may have been around as much as a decade.

The story comprised a perfectly unassuming chap, a regular guy - a bit parrochial and staid perhaps who's identity was stolen. He awoke in a place far from Earth, but still a part of the galactic community that Earth belonged to. He also discovered that his body and all identifying paperwork/tags/belongings were gone, he was alone in an alien culture.

The story covered his inner struggles with what he had to do to get home again and regain his life/body, and the adventure of doing so. He might go through a few bodies on the way, not sure.

The book-cover: This had the picture in portrait of the guy with a sad, lost look and maybe tusks, wrinkles and short tentacles for hair. I vaguely remember his skin was a tone of purple.

Comment: Like [this](http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/1/15/MNDSWP1973.jpg) maybe? Or one of [these](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?9685)?

Comment: The story you remember reading, do you recall how it ends? Does the guy ever get back to Earth?

Comment: I don't recall how it ends @user14111, but yes, this is Sheckley's Mindswap, the first link was the cover, I added the tusks in my head. Full text at [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v23n05_1965-06/mode/2up). Thanks. Voting to close as dupe..

Comment: Your Internet Archive link is to the version published in *Galaxy* which is probably shorter than the full novel. The latter can be borrowed (free but registration required) from the Archive: https://archive.org/details/mindswap00robe

Comment: Thanks again, I was following the link from the other version of the question, didn't check properly, great find @user14111